# What do I use to enter obscured input in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to obtain a Social Security Number in my app, but I don't want the number itself to display in the interface.  How do I go about obtaining the input without disclosing the confidential information on the screen?

I have to fill up this application which asking for my social security system number but instead of writing down the numbers it should appear as XXX-XX-XXXX rather than the number itsself because it's confidential.

Comment: sss? xxxx? No code, no help...

Comment: If you give a bit more detail then we might actually stand a chance. :)

Comment: No title ever provided less helpful information. Good job.

Comment: Voting to close, this is nonsense.

Comment: He wants to know how to make his social security number appear like *** as a password might when entering it into a form!

Comment: yes

0
i have to fill up this application which asking for my social security system number but instead of writing down the numbers it should appear there XXXXXX rather than the number its self bec its confidential..

Comment: This question is badly formatted, but it's not as nonsensical as most of you made it out to be. Felix's answer seems correct, so this wasn't unanswerable.

Comment: @vernadith -- you have a valid question, but you've worded it poorly.  I've tried to capture your intent.  Please rollback the edit if I've missed the mark.

Comment: This is where the reputation system breaks down. Although what he asked was decipherable he's gaining reputation from getting upvotes now someone else has rephrased his question and the -4 doesn't seem justified. Seems a bit unbalanced really.

Comment: Next time try to write a decently-phrased question - don't rely on the community to edit it for you and decipher what you want. Make it clear, precise, and include all the details you can.

Comment: For some reason, I smell a scam here... he doesn't know how to use XCode or Interface Builder and yet he wants the user to input their SSNs. For one, I don't think Apple would like the collection of SSNs in general...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [secure text field](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextField/Concepts/AboutSecureTextFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000127-BAJCGDIH) instead of a normal text field ([`NSSecureTextField`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSecureTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

But I bet interface builder lets you just drag and drop this field.

**Update:**

And in fact it does:

[IB http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/1207/1007040002.png](http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/1207/1007040002.png)

Comment: please tell me how? what to do?

Comment: @vernadith: If you don't know how to program in Objective-C or how to use Interface Builder, then you have to learn this first. How did you manage to create your application so far?

Comment: please give me the exact site where i can download this  NSSecureTextField that can format my sss number to xxxx

Comment: @vernadith: Do you develop for iPhone or for Mac?

Comment: @jrtc27: Well, I don't know. The `iphone` tag was added by someone else and from the original question it is not clear whether it is iPhone or Mac.

Comment: @Felix Kling "What do I use to enter obscured input in an *iPhone* app?"

Comment: @jrtc27: This was also edited by another user. Have a look at the revisions: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3174756/revisions and tell me if you can find which platform he is developing for.

Comment: How could so many people have upvoted this when it's the wrong answer? I'm sure Felix meant well (or answered before the iPhone angle was highlighted), but I just lost a little bit of faith in SO. Vernadith, you should go back and unaccept it.

Comment: @Joost Schuur: I did mean well :) The original question didn't contain anything that one could even *assume* that it is about iPhone. And I don't know how the others concluded that. I cannot find the slightest hint in the OP's question or comments that it's about iPhone. Until this cannot be ensured, I won't delete my answer. I lost some faith too... but more because some people seem to edit questions how the like it...

Comment: @Felix King: I didn't recognize the extent of editing that had gone on when I posted my comment. Details were 'obscured' (heh) behind the 'add/show more comments' link. No hard feelings. Time to go outside and enjoy some of that good weather it seems...

Answer (score 1):

NSSecureTextField is the equivelant of a password field in the iPhone.

Here's the description from Apple:

> A secure text field is a type of text
>   field that hides its text from display
>   or other access via the user
>   interface. It’s suitable for use as a
>   password-entry object, or for any item
>   in which a secure value must be kept.
>   Your code can get the text field’s
>   string value using the standard
>   stringValue method, but users can’t
>   see it or access it. It overrides many
>   aspects of text editing to prevent
>   passing of the object’s value out by
>   mechanisms available to the user
>   (namely, through Cut, Copy, and Paste
>   commands, and the Services facility).
>   This object also overrides the text
>   system’s drawing routine to draw no
>   text at all) . . . **Every method in NSSecureTextFieldCell has a cover in NSSecureTextField. (A cover is a method of the same name that calls the original method.**   http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextField/Concepts/AboutSecureTextFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000127-BAJCGDIH

Since NSSecureTextField derives from NSTextField, you can find any tutorial on the web on how to use NSTextField -- simply swap NSTextField for NSSecureTextField in the implementation.  I bolded the important phrase above (*Every method in NSSecureTextFieldCell has a cover in NSSecureTextField*).  Interact with the NSSecureTextField just as you would a NSTextField object, the interface is exactly the same at the API level.

The NSSecureTextField will show up in an application looking like this:

[image]

When I searched Google for "NSTextField Tutorial", the first result I found was from the following website:
http://www.pietrop.com/wordpress/dev-area/tutorials/cocoa-tutorial-nstextfield-nsbutton/#english

In short, you'll end up with a header that looks something like this:

```
//  Controller.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Controller : NSObject
{
    //IBOutlets (the inteface's controllers)
    IBOutlet NSSecureTextField *inputText;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *displayedText;
    IBOutlet NSButton *updateButton;
    IBOutlet NSButton *clearButton;
}

/* IBActions (the user interface interactions) */
//Updates the text in the Wrapping Label
- (IBAction)updateText:(id)sender;

//Clears the text in the Wrapping Label and in the TextField
- (IBAction)clearText:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Isn't all that just for Cocoa under Mac OS? It starts with NS for starters and not UI like the iPhone UIKit elements, and the tutorial you link to makes no reference to the iPhone. I don't understand why you interspersed that iPhone snap shot there. It's misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The standard UITextField for the iPhone has a 'secure' option under Text Input Traits options in Interface Builder. Try that.